# tkinter ttk widgets ignoring background color?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using `tkinter`'s themed (`ttk`) GUI toolkit for an application. Trying to apply some uniform styling to the widgets in the main window:

```
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('.', background='#eeeeee')
s.configure('.', font=('Helvetica', 14))
self.configure(background='#eeeeee')
```

The font change works great, but for some reason the widgets (i.e. `ttk.Label` and `ttk.Button`) don't seem to reflect the background change, which is pretty obvious visually due to contrast between the window's background and the widget's. If I check what it's set to:

```
label1.cget('background')
```

it returns `''`, so clearly it's not being set, but I don't understand what's wrong given the docs for [ttk.Label](https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Label.html) and [styles](https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-style-layer.html). Trying to set the background for a single label directly:

```
label1.configure(background='#eeeeee')
```

also doesn't work (i.e. no change).
Any ideas?

Comment: Let me guess, you are using a Mac system.

Comment: Yep, I'm on 10.9. Is this a known issue with OS X?

Comment: Yes. At least it was. I am not using OS X, so not sure if it still an on going issue.

Comment: ttk Label background work fine on Windows.

Comment: Anyone using tk should really use the most recent tcl/tk release they can, with the latest features and perhaps more importantly, the latest bug fixes.  The python.org 3.7.0b3 installer includes and installs for Python's use tcl/tk 8.6.8.  This should be a big improvements over even the last bugfix of 8.5, which was the latest tcl/tk support on Mac before 3.7.  It is supposed to have several fixes for macOS.  Whether this issue is fixed, I don't know.

Comment: 2019/08/08 UPDATE:
Still doesn't work the ttk.Style as it should, so just change the theme_use to 'default' for now.. Im actually programming on MAC HIGH SIERRA, and Python 3.7.1, Tcl/Tk 8.6

Answer (score 10):

I was having this problem as well, and I believe the issue is ttk's "aqua" theme, which is the default on OSX, doesn't respect background colour configuration in a number of widgets. I solved the problem by setting the theme to "default", which immediately caused all widgets' backgrounds to appear as specified.

Here's my basic example:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

root = tkinter.Tk()
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.theme_use('classic')
style.configure('Test.TLabel', background= 'red')
text = ttk.Label(root, text= 'Hello', style= 'Test.TLabel')
text.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Try changing `style.theme_use('classic')` to `style.theme_use('aqua')` to see the issue.

Comment: Indeed, switching the theme to 'classic' fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had that too, I think it is a ttk bug, is caused by some computers and can't be fixed. Just have a big rectangle using the draw function in the background having the background color. I can't think of anything else, either.

Answer (score 1):

2018 update: tkinter.ttk.Label instance still does not respect the 'background' configuration option, so I switched back to using tkinter.Label for the time being and am submitting it as a bug to python developers (at least remove it from the available options if it won't respect it). I'm using python 3.6.5 with Tk 8.6. Here is an output of an interactive session to demonstrate:

```
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> import tkinter.ttk as ttk
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> tk_label = tk.Label(root)
>>> tk_label.keys()
['activebackground', 'activeforeground', 'anchor', 'background', 'bd', 'bg', 'bitmap', 'borderwidth', 'compound', 'cursor', 'disabledforeground', 'fg', 'font', 'foreground', 'height', 'highlightbackground', 'highlightcolor', 'highlightthickness', 'image', 'justify', 'padx', 'pady', 'relief', 'state', 'takefocus', 'text', 'textvariable', 'underline', 'width', 'wraplength']
>>> tk_label.config(text='Old style tkinter.Label instance', foreground='blue', background='red')
>>> tk_label.pack()
>>> new_ttk_label = ttk.Label(root)
>>> new_ttk_label.keys()
['background', 'foreground', 'font', 'borderwidth', 'relief', 'anchor', 'justify', 'wraplength', 'takefocus', 'text', 'textvariable', 'underline', 'width', 'image', 'compound', 'padding', 'state', 'cursor', 'style', 'class']
>>> new_ttk_label.config(text='New tkinter.ttk.Label instance', foreground='blue', background='blue')
>>> new_ttk_label.pack()
>>> tk_label.config('background')
('background', 'background', 'Background', <border object: 'White'>, 'red')
>>> new_ttk_label.config('background')
('background', 'frameColor', 'FrameColor', '', <border object: 'blue'>)
>>> new_ttk_label.config('foreground')
('foreground', 'textColor', 'TextColor', '', <color object: 'blue'>)
>>> root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Update: reported to python bug-tracker, was told that tkinter module is a simple wrapper around tk/tcl and to report bug reports there instead, so I have reported the bug to them.

Comment: 2022 update: can confirm that `ttk.Label` still does not except a background color on macOS. Usure about other OSes.`tk.Label` appears to work okay