# How to change the color of ttk button

Tags: python, button, tkinter, ttk

I am using Python 3.x on Windows.

My problem is I want to customize a button widget of `ttk` by completely changing its background and foreground color.  But so far, I have been unsuccessful.

My desired button is:

[image]

I read the [`ttk.Style`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html#ttk.Style) guide and used their code:

```
ttk.Style().configure("TButton", padding=6, relief="flat",
   background="#000")

btn = ttk.Button(text="Sample")
btn.pack()
```

But it's changing the border color instead of the whole button bakground.  Here is the output:

[image]

Kindly help me achieve my desired button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter ttk widgets ignoring background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750141/tkinter-ttk-widgets-ignoring-background-color)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't an easy way to change the foreground of a button from the `ttk` library.  It is always the standard Windows gray like in your picture.

But you can easily get what you want with a normal `tkinter.Button` if you set the right options.  Below is an example script:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
btn = tk.Button(root, 
                bg='#000000',
                fg='#b7f731',
                relief='flat',
                text='hello button',
                width=20)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

And here is what it will look like:

[image]

Also, the shade of green I picked was just an example one that I thought was pretty close to what you wanted.  But you can specify any hex color code you want.  If you need to turn a RGB value into hex, a simple trick is to use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) like so:

```
>>> rgb = (183, 247, 49)
>>> '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(*rgb)
'#b7f731'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked but is there any example with ttk ??

Comment: i want to do it with ttk @iCodez

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible (I could be wrong though).  `ttk.Button` is a special kind of button that is designed to be identical to the standard Windows button.  If you want a different look, then there is really no reason to use the `ttk.Button`.  The normal Tkinter button does what you want just fine.

Comment: Otherwise, you have about three options: 1) use a different GUI toolkit besides Tkinter.  This could be either wxpython or Qt. 2) create an image of the button you want and use that instead, or 3) alter the `ttk` source code to use a different look.  Other than that, your best bet is to use the normal `tkinter.Button`.

Answer (score 22):

Although it is not as simple as with Tk buttons, it is possible. In ttk, if you set the theme_use attribute to any of these: ('winnative', 'clam', 'alt', 'default', 'classic', 'vista', 'xpnative'), you should be able to modify the default behaviour. I set the "style.map" attribute to avoid background colour change due to mouse hover (The state of the button is always 'active').

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk 

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('alt')
style.configure('TButton', background = 'red', foreground = 'white', width = 20, borderwidth=1, focusthickness=3, focuscolor='none')
style.map('TButton', background=[('active','red')])

root = tk.Tk()
button = ttk.Button(root,text='Quit')
button.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.4)  
root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

*CONTEXT: Debian based computers*

**SHORT EXAMPLE:**

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
button_1 = ttk.Button(root, text='click me')
style.theme_use('alt')
style.configure('TButton', font=('American typewriter', 14), background='#232323', foreground='white')
style.map('TButton', background=[('active', '#ff0000')])
button_1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**LONG EXAMPLE:**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class App:
    def __init__(self):

        # Window setup
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title('BUTTONS')
        WIDTH, HEIGHT = 300, 500
        INITIAL_X_POSITION, INITIAL_Y_POSITION = 450, 200
        self.root.geometry(f'{WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}+{INITIAL_X_POSITION}+{INITIAL_Y_POSITION}')
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.style = ttk.Style()

        # Layout
        self.button_1 = ttk.Button(self.root, text='click me', command=self.show_me_pi)
        self.style.theme_use('alt')
        self.style.configure('TButton', font=('American typewriter', 14), background='#232323', foreground='white')
        self.style.map('TButton',
                       background=[('active', '#ff0000'), ('disabled', '#f0f0f0')]

                       )
        self.button_1.pack()

        self.button_2 = ttk.Button(self.root, text='click me', state='disabled')
        self.button_2.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def show_me_pi(self):
        py_label = Label(self.root, text='3.14159', font=('American typewriter', 20))
        py_label.pack()


app_runner = App()
```

Comment: MacOSX is not so compatible with Tkinter colors so simply changing the color the way you would on a Windows-based machine is prone to fail. So following the code above is a way around that incompatibility. In addition, here is an awesome webpage that covers this Tkinter properties matter in detail: https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/button.html

Comment: As of 2022, this seems to be the only answer that works (with Python3 on Ubuntu).

Comment: is there any way to make it a particular color without having to hover over it?

Comment: @Dekriel , yup, the `background='#232323'` in this code is giving the button a dark grayish tinge. So you might use that tag to change it to a particular color of your choice. Peace out.

Answer (score 2):

```
import ttk

root.style = ttk.Style()
#root.style.theme_use("clam")
style.configure('TButton', background='black')
style.configure('TButton', foreground='green')
button= ttk.Button(self, text="My background is black and my foreground is green.")
```

works for me if you want to change *all* your buttons to the one you "desire", with Python 2.7 and Tkinter 8.6

Comment: This seems to be the same as what the OP did themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the key is to change the name of the style you're applying to the button from Custom.TButton to Custom.TLabel.
For example:

```
style = ttk.Style()
ttk.Style().configure("Custom.TLabel", padding=6, relief="flat",
   background="#000")

btn = ttk.Button(text="Sample", style="Custom.TLabel")
btn.pack()
```

Or a full program:

```
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('Custom.TLabel', background='red')

slider = ttk.Button(root, text="Hello World", style='Custom.TLabel')
slider.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```