# Binding a Color to a Button in Tkinter Results in a TclError

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently trying to implement code into my program to update a buttons color when the user hovers the mouse cursor over it. The program recognizes the hover, but returns an error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\oiest\Documents\Programs\iNTMI\v1.1.3b\iNTMI.py", line 252, in <lambda>
    achievementsButton.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: achievementsButton.configure(bg = "red"))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1270, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1261, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg"
```

I had Googled how to do the changing of colors when hovering and found the following code. Though for some reason, it does not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
    achievementsButton.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: achievementsButton.configure(bg = "red"))
    achievementsButton.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: achievementsButton.configure(bg = "white"))
```

This is the code from where I originally defined achievementsButton.

```
    achievementsButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Achievements", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(achievements), width = "25")
```

Answer (score 1):

`ttk.Button` instances do not have a `bg` or `background` attribute. There are two solutions:

- Use an ordinary `tkinter.Button`, which does have a bg attribute.
- Keep using the ttk.Button, and configure it using a style object. See [Using and customizing ttk styles](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-style-layer.html) for more information. Example:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
root = Tk()
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure("regular.TButton", background="red")
s.configure("onhover.TButton", background="white")
button = ttk.Button(root, style="regular.TButton")
button.pack()
button.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: button.configure(style="onhover.TButton"))
button.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: button.configure(style="regular.TButton"))
root.mainloop()
```

However, this will only change the background color of the area behind the actual button, rather than the button's face. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27347981/how-to-change-the-color-of-ttk-button)
 post seems to indicate that it's impossible to change the face color of a ttk Button.

Comment: So there is no actual way to keep the nice button design of Windows 7/8/10 using ttk? That's a little disappointing, but you did help me. Thank you.