# Tkinter Hovering over Button -> Color change

Tags: python, tkinter, hover

Is there a possibility to change the background-color of a `Button` after hovering on it? What is the code for this in Tkinter?

Comment: After hovering over it or *while* hovering over it? Are you using ttk? Please show us a [mcve] of your code.

Comment: `Button`s have options you can pass when constructing one that control their color when the cursor is over them called `activebackground` and `activeforeground`, try setting and using those. Here's some [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/button.html).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Sadly the `activebackground` and `activeforeground` options only seem to work when you are clicking on the button rather than when you hover over the button. Use the `<Leave>` and `<Enter>` events instead

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_enter(e):
    myButton['background'] = 'green'

def on_leave(e):
    myButton['background'] = 'SystemButtonFace'

root = tk.Tk()
myButton = tk.Button(root,text="Click Me")
myButton.grid()


myButton.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
myButton.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)

root.mainloop()
```

As pointed out in the comments, if we want multiple buttons, we can bind the buttons to functions that use the event data for the click event to change the background of the button.

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_enter(e):
    e.widget['background'] = 'green'

def on_leave(e):
    e.widget['background'] = 'SystemButtonFace'

root = tk.Tk()
myButton = tk.Button(root,text="Click Me")
myButton.grid()


myButton.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
myButton.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)

myButton2 = tk.Button(root,text="Click Me")
myButton2.grid()


myButton2.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
myButton2.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)

root.mainloop()
```

A slicker way to do it for multiple buttons would be to create a new Button class that modifies the behaviour of the default button so that the `activebackground` actually works when you hover.

```
import tkinter as tk

class HoverButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        tk.Button.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)
        self.defaultBackground = self["background"]
        self.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

    def on_enter(self, e):
        self['background'] = self['activebackground']

    def on_leave(self, e):
        self['background'] = self.defaultBackground

root = tk.Tk()

classButton = HoverButton(root,text="Classy Button", activebackground='green')
classButton.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What if I want to change the image in the button when I hover over it?

Comment: @RajMehta Ask a new question.

Comment: A simpler way to handle multiple `Button`s that does require defining a subclass would be by making the bound functions get the widget from the event argument they are passed — i.e. in function `on_enter():` use `e.widget.config(background='green'))` instead of `myButton['background'] = 'green'`.

Comment: @martineau I've updated the answer to include this option too.

Comment: scotty3785: Yep, that's how to make the callbacks reusable, as I suggested — so now your answer's even more comprehensive. `;¬)`

Comment: This is such a great solution.

@RajMehta, I believe that you could just use the `on_enter` and `on_leave` functions, with code to change the image inside the method.

Answer (score 7):

**Plain and simple**

*Context: Unix based computers, might not work for Windows nor MACOSX*

*In your `Button` object properties you have the tags: `activebackground` & `activeforeground` that are activated whenever there is interaction with the instace created. That is: the button object you've created.*

e.g.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

button = Button(root, text="Click me", bg="#000", fg="#fff", activebackground="#f00", activeforeground="#fff")
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I almost skipped trying this answer because of the comments above and the fact that it had no votes.  This should be the accepted answer.  It works perfectly on mouseover for me on Linux python3.

Comment: One thing that must be brought to heed's the fact that, there is the Button and the ttk.Button objects. See the solution for the ttk.Button object -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27347981/how-to-change-the-color-of-ttk-button/65729636#65729636

Comment: I think it has been upvoted less due to the fact that it doesn't seem to work for hovering within Windows 10, where many GUI apps are distributed.