# Change button images when you hover over them tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can I change the image when hovering over the button?
I need that when you hover over the button 1 or 2 the picture changes:

```
Photo1 = (file='Image\ProgrammingButton') 
Photo2 = (file='Image\DesignButton')  
But1 = (root, image=Photo1) 
But2 = (root, image=Photo2)
```

On hover

```
Photo1 = (file='Image\ActiveProgrammingButton') 
Photo2 = (file='Image\ActiveDesignButton')
```

Comment: this will help you to understand the principal mechanism. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49896477/3700626

Comment: I've already seen this article. I was able to make the buttons change, but only for one picture. But that's not exactly what I need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tkinter has 'enter' and 'leave' events which you have to bind to some function and you can change the image using the `config` method.

Here is a demonstration:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def onEnter(event):
    global img
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r'img2'))
    btn.config(image=img)

def onLeave(event):
    global img
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r'img1'))
    btn.config(image=img)
    

root = Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r'img1')) 

btn = Button(root, image=img)
btn.pack()

btn.bind('<Enter>',  onEnter)
btn.bind('<Leave>',  onLeave)

root.mainloop()
```

If you want this effect for many buttons. I would suggest you create your own button inheriting the `Button` class.

Here is an example.

Thx to @furas suggestion. Here is the updated class

```py
class Btn(Button):

    def __init__(self, root, img1, img2, *args, **kwargs):       
        super().__init__(root, *args, **kwargs)

        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(img1))
        self.img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(img2))

        self['image'] = self.img
        
        self.bind('<Enter>', self.enter)
        self.bind('<Leave>', self.leave)
        
    def enter(self, event):
        self.config(image=self.img2)

    def leave(self, event):
        self.config(image=self.img)
```

How to use:
Just specify your image path in the img1 and img2 parameter

Here is an example:

```
img = r'path1' 
img2 = r'path2'

btn = Btn(root, img1=img, img2=img2)
btn.pack()
```

Comment: How to use it for multiple buttons?

Comment: @zefercka how many buttons. Did you assign a variable to each button? or are you iterating?

Comment: I have 5 buttons, each has its own variable

Comment: @zefercka added an update. Tell me you have any other queries

Comment: in class you could even create both `PhotoImage` in `__init__` and later use only `config()`. But I wondering if you no need `root` in `super().__init__(root, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: @furas True you could do that. I forgot to add root in super. Thx for pointing out.