# Tkinter Hover on Button by Brus Espinal (youtube)

Tags: python, tkinter, button, mousehover

good day.

I'm new with Python coding. Currently, I'm watching videos in youtube for additional knowledge. I came up with a design (in mind) to work with and I stumble upon this video by Brus Espinal (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCFvBE0ilzc) and that's the hover effect I've been imagining.

I've watch other videos too with hover effect using Enter, Leave and .bind. But Brus's code was simple. All he do was to use the module or call another function  "from button_hover import hover". I literally copied his code to try if it works on my end. But got an error "no module". I tried pip install button_hover but to no avail.

I tried contacting him, but unable to have a reply.

Anyone here knows how to pip install the said module.
Is it a "user" made/created module/package?

Comment: Probably You don't have tkinter installed or You are not importing it right. Hard to say without code snippet

Comment: You probably have to install this on your device. But for that, the user must make this available to pypi. Anyaway if you are interested, you can copy/download [this](https://github.com/nihaalnz/mtk/blob/main/mbuttons.py) py file and place in your directory and import it from your file giving the name and directly use it like your buttons.

Answer (score 1):

The `button_hover` here is his (Brus) module made by him, you need to get his source code to import that module

EDIT: If you want to make button change color when hover, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888623/tkinter-hovering-over-button-color-change) is some tutorial

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the help!